# PHP if condition on the basis of matching text

Tags: php

I am trying to add one condition to show `"mi"` but instead it is showing me the `"Mileage"`

here is my code

```
<?php if (esc_html_e($data_value['single_name'], 'motors') == "mi") {echo "mi";} ?>
```

Comment: You're checking if `esc_html_e($data_value['single_name'], 'motors') == "mi"` then promptly doing nothing...

Comment: There is no code

Comment: the code is there

Comment: can you echo out esc_html_e($data_value['single_name'], 'motors') to see if it actually equals "mi"

Comment: you don't show code that echos out "Mileage". I believe that your if statement is simply failing to translate the value in $data_value['single_name'] . 

Also try to echo out $data_value['single_name'] before your if and see what value it takes. 
One final step is to check documentation on escape_html_e
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo esc_attr(ucfirst($data_meta)); ?>
```

prints the value of $data_meta with the first character in upper case

```
<?php if (esc_html_e($data_value['single_name'], 'motors') == "mi") ?>
```

checks if $data_value['single_name'] is equal to mi.

so...I'm assuming you want something like

```
if ( esc_attr(ucfirst($data_meta)) == "Mileage" ) { echo "mi"; }
```

Comment: yes , but it is not showing `"mi"`